# Missing source when conecting bus line to mux

Tags: vhdl, fpga, bus

When I connect "MyMux2" with a bus-line to the ADCdriver (see picture) I get error messages like: **"Error (12009): Node "Misc:b2v_inst|data_mymux2_2x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI6Ap.jpg)" is missing source"**.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Yes. Apparently nothing is driving that signal. Find what is supposed to be driving it, it's one of the blocks in your image, and find out why it isn't driving it. If you can't see what's wrong by a simple visual inspection, the obvious question is, did that block work correctly in simulation?

Comment: The simulation is working. The input bus (islv_adc_data[13..0]) is divided and comes from both Mux (see block mappings). I think there is a naming error or something like this because the upper block does not give an error message although it goes in the same bus (islv_adc_dataX). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port `islv_adc_data` is an input of the entity `ADCdriver`. Your are connecting this input only with another input of the multiplexer `MyMux2`. Thus, the signal `data_mymux2_2x[1]` and all the other ones of that bus have no driver.

Comment: But in which way I connect the signals coming from **MyMux1** AND **MyMux2** to the same input **islv_adc_data** from the entity **ADCdriver**? I think I need to connect both bus lines together but the question is how...

Comment: The bus signal `data_mymux2_2x` is not coming from the mux, it is going to the mux in the meaning of data transmission. You have to connect the input of `MyMux2` to an output of `ADCdriver`, e.g. `oslv_adc_data`. Or you have to connect the output of `MyMux2` to the input of the ADC.

Comment: I think you solved the problem! The problem is that I connected the input of the **ADCdriver islv_adc_data[x]** with the input of **MyMux2**. Actually I would need a Demux in order to use the input of the **ADCdriver islv_adc_data[x]**. Unfortunately I can not find a Demux in the Libraries.